# Cannot display numpy matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have had some difficulties to display my numpy matrix as a [colormap](https://imgur.com/a/otlXnXQ) using matplotlib.
But when doing so I keep running in the same error over and over again, regardless of what I try:
TypeError: Dimensions of C (1000, 64) should be one smaller than X(1000) and Y(64) while using shading='flat' see help(pcolormesh)

This is my actual code and the full output:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def readFile(f):

    with open(f) as file:
        array2d = [[float(digit) for digit in line.split()] for line in file]

    return np.asmatrix(array2d)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = readFile("data.log")
    # Ensure data has the correct shape
    print(str(data))
    print(str(data.shape))
    data = data[:1000, :64]
    print(str(data.shape))

    # Create x and y values
    x = np.linspace(0, 1000, 1000)  # 1000 points from 0 to 999
    y = np.linspace(0, 64, 64)  # 64 points from 0 to 63
    
    # Create a meshgrid from x and y
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    
    # Plot the 2D color map using pcolormesh
    plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, data, cmap='viridis', shading='flat')  # No need to transpose data matrix
    
    # Add a colorbar
    cbar = plt.colorbar(label='Colorbar Label')
    
    # Add labels and title
    plt.xlabel('X-axis Label')
    plt.ylabel('Y-axis Label')
    plt.title('2D Color Map with pcolormesh')
    
    # Show the plot
    plt.show()
```

The full output:

```
[[1884. 1874. 1904. ... 1874. 2248. 1848.]
 [  77.   59.   68. ...   62.   78.   80.]
 [  68.   50.   41. ...   59.   50.   41.]
 ...
 [  41.   41.   41. ...   41.   41.   41.]
 [  41.   41.   41. ...   41.   41.   41.]
 [  41.   41.   41. ...   41.   41.   41.]]
(1000, 64)
(1000, 64)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "visualizer.py", line 32, in <module>
    plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, data, cmap='viridis', shading='flat')  # No need to transpose data matrix
  File "C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2773, in pcolormesh
    __ret = gca().pcolormesh(
  File "C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1473, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 6218, in pcolormesh
    X, Y, C, shading = self._pcolorargs('pcolormesh', *args,
  File "C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5749, in _pcolorargs
    raise TypeError(f"Dimensions of C {C.shape} should"
TypeError: Dimensions of C (1000, 64) should be one smaller than X(1000) and Y(64) while using shading='flat' see help(pcolormesh)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error text says it. You should have the parameter `C` (data) one smaller in both dimensions than X and Y, when you use shading='flat'.  So, instead of

```py
data = data[:1000, :64]
```

this case it should be

```py
data = data[:999, :63]
```

Another option would be to change the `shading` argument to be 'nearest' or 'gouraud' ([docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html#matplotlib-pyplot-pcolormesh)) :

> If shading='nearest' or 'gouraud', the dimensions of X and Y should be the same as those of C

#### About call signature

Also note that your C (`data`)  has, after making it smaller, shape (999, 63) but your X and Y have dimensions of (64, 1000). To fix this, you could transpose `data` with `data.T`;

```py
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, data.T, cmap='viridis', shading='flat')
```

or alternatively, transpose both X and Y:

```py
plt.pcolormesh(X.T, Y.T, data, cmap='viridis', shading='flat')
```

In addition, the data type of `C` (here: `data`) must be array-like, so should either convert your matrix into array with `data = np.array(data)` or replace `np.asmatrix` with `np.array`.

Comment: Didn't work exactly the same issue:

File "C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5749, in _pcolorargs
  raise TypeError(f"Dimensions of C {C.shape} should"
TypeError: Dimensions of C (999, 63) should be one smaller than X(1000) and Y(64) while using shading='flat' see help(pcolormesh)

Comment: Full output: https://pastebin.com/NQbMysDZ

Comment: I see you made a comment wrt the function signature, how would you suggest me to change my implementation so it properly fits the signature?

Comment: You should just take the transpose of either (a) C (your `data`) or (b) both X and Y. Transpose is taken with `.T`. So, for example `data = data.T`.

Comment: Updated the answer for call signature.

Comment: Try with `plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, data.T, cmap='viridis', shading='flat')`. The [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html#matplotlib-pyplot-pcolormesh) had the call signature `pcolormesh([X, Y,] C, **kwargs)` but also I tried it and it does not work.

Comment: Nope, didn't work. So here when I try you [first recommendation](https://pastebin.com/QAAyacHS), and this is the [second recomendation](https://pastebin.com/h5b0j3eJ) (output is below each time)

Comment: Could you confirm the shapes of all the first three arguments? It looks like it's working for me: https://pastebin.com/v6iRYh2B

Comment: capital x shape: (64, 1000)
capital y shape: (64, 1000)
data: (999, 63)

Comment: I wonder where matplotlib gets the shape `(1, 62937)` ? Do you have some variable with that shape?

Comment: Not that I know of... All code is posted in my comments where you can see all the shapes etc...

Comment: It seems to be 999 * 63. I can't seem to reproduce this on my machine. What's your matplotlib version ? `python -m pip list | grep matplotlib`

Comment: matplotlib                    3.7.4

Comment: Does this work for you? https://pastebin.com/v1ZWLykR (it works on my machine with matplotlib 3.7.1)

Comment: Yup your code snippet works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256292/discussion-between-traducerad-and-niko-fohr).